# Make an invisible SwiftUI to UIKit to SwiftUI bridge

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swiftui

I have found out some features are terribly lacking on the SwiftUI side, especially on the interactions. So I am trying to add up an in-betweener "invisible" UIViewController sandwiched between two UIViews.

TL;DR: See point 1 below.

For example, to make sure a view can receive a UIDrop interaction, or to add an UIDrag interaction, or any other interaction that can actually be influenced by other softwares (such as an iPad drag from another software to mine).

So I created a little piece of fun code that actually simply wraps around a View "Content" and gets called when the view is actually instantiated. I wanted to forego the Controller part but it doesn't seem possible on the iOS part of the equation, only macOS. Boo. Anyways, I know these features will probably eventually be added to SwiftUI, so the obvious goal of that bridge is to be as transparent as possible, so I can remove it whenever the proper way gets added to SwiftUI.

It mostly works, believe it or not! But there is a nitpick and a bug, and maybe someone actually did something similar and could actually help me figure it out. And maybe my code will help someone else as a good starting point.

*(SwiftUI 11.0 beta 5)*

1. *(Bug and main question)* It seems the frame size isn't propagated. So the parent of my class must actually hard-code `.frame(width: something, height: something)` or else my view will not be of a proper size... Which makes sense, as I don't actually propagate these values nor retrieve them from the Content. I tried hugging the size, but the frame size is not sent. Where and how should I get this value transmitted across the board. The goal of my code is to make this bridge as lean, efficient and invisible as possible to SwiftUI, developer and the end user.
2. *(Nitpick)* I found the `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad` and other load-time operations are not actually called. `viewWillAppear`, for example, isn't called at view-time. If I navigate deeper and go back, then `viewWillAppear` will be called, but not the first time it's shown. So I resorted in creating a temporary "initialized" variable. What am I doing wrong (if any)?
3. Maybe I'm also forgetting to transmit other data across the classes and structs. For example, the UIViewController actually makes the object's background white. It could be transparent, but for me it's of no importance (I guess you can add `self.view.backgroundColor = .clear`). If you think of improvements, I'd be very happy to know about it!

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// Creates a SwiftUI to UIKit to SwiftUI bridge, where a lambda is called on viewWillAppear
struct UIKitBridgeView<Content>: View where Content : View {
    var content: () -> Content
    var onViewWillAppear: (UIView)->Void

    init(onViewWillAppear: @escaping (UIView)->Void, _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.onViewWillAppear = onViewWillAppear
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {

    }

    /// This is the class in UIKit that can host a SwiftUI "Content" type.
    class HostingController: UIHostingController<Content> {
        var onViewWillAppear: ((UIView)->Void)?
        var initialized: Bool = false

        init(_ content: () -> Content) {
            super.init(rootView: content())
            self.onViewWillAppear = nil
        }

        init(_ content: () -> Content, _ onViewWillAppear: @escaping (UIView)->Void) {
            super.init(rootView: content())
            self.onViewWillAppear = onViewWillAppear
        }

        @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            self.onViewWillAppear = nil
        }

        func update(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerRepresentable>) {
            if !initialized {
                initialized = true
                if let onViewWillAppear = self.onViewWillAppear {
                    onViewWillAppear(self.view)
                }
                // self.view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical) doesn't seem to do anything...
                // self.view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
            }
        }
    }

    /// This is the struct in SwiftUI that can host a UIKit's ViewController
    struct ViewControllerRepresentable : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        let content: () -> Content
        var onViewWillAppear: ((UIView)->Void)?

        init(_ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
            self.content = content
            self.onViewWillAppear = nil
        }

        init(_ content: @escaping () -> Content, _ onViewWillAppear: @escaping (UIView)->Void) {
            self.content = content
            self.onViewWillAppear = onViewWillAppear
        }

        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> HostingController {
            self.onViewWillAppear != nil ?
                HostingController(self.content, self.onViewWillAppear!) :
                HostingController(self.content)
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ hostingController: HostingController, context: Context) {
            hostingController.update(context: context)
        }

        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ViewControllerRepresentable(self.content, self.onViewWillAppear)
    }
}
```

For a point 1 incomplete example :

```swift
UIKitBridgeView(onViewWillAppear: { (view) in
    if let delegate = self.appState.dragInteractionDelegate {
        view.addInteraction(self.createDraggable(delegate))
    }
}) {
    Spacer()            // Insert what you want here
}.frame(width: 50, height: 50)
```

And the `.frame(width, height)` really annoys me!

Comment: No idea, but does it transfer `@EnvironmentObjects` too?

Comment: @Fabian the Content type is actually passed from the parent, so it's created in the parent (see the instantiation point in ```HostingController```'s init where it actually executes the ```content()``` variable...) So yes, the ```@EnvironmentObject``` values are respected.

Comment: Wow, that's neat. Though it may not necessarily pass on updates (probably changes yes, but no notification to ui to redraw). See  [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/P4D89WTr) for an example. Should it somehow use transactions or something? Or the ominous .update() which can't be called? I have no idea how one would do that. That does not help with the frame thing though.. sadly no idea how to fix it. Probably some protocol.

Comment: @Fabian true that. My hunch on the code creation, though, is to keep what's inside pretty much as a "black box", where things sandwiched in the View-UIViewController-View part are not important. So in this case, you actually get much more than you bargained for. Since the ViewBuilder is responsible for all parts, and the UI* counterparts knows about the changes, the ```update``` function is properly called whenever something changes, and the updated view does get called, which in turn calls back the updater. Through keeping that Content as a lambda, I do not bypass update systems.

Comment: @Fabian but you are right not everything is called at all times, which is IMHO a problem. My wet dream would be to have something equivalent to Group, which doesn't do a thing in itself, and passes things to its child as if nothing.

Comment: I tried the GeometryReader, but let it go. Not only is it really wasteful in resources, but it's also hard to send the data to the child and parent, and it doesn't solve the problem that frame() operation is a bidirectional operation, where the Content needs to react to Min, Max, Proposed, and return a proper size, where everything in-between must simply get the values, acknowledge, and update their sizes.

Comment: Problem is I/we don't know how the whole thing is implemented exactly. To fix it properly it would have to be open source :(. But a very nice try. I think I better stop before going down the rabbit hole :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198147/discussion-between-michel-donais-and-fabian).